# Ryzen 5 or 7 CPU for Davinci Resolve 14

Tags: processor, video-editing

I am looking to build an editing PC and one of the crucial components is CPU.

However, it seems like Davinci Resolve run almost entirely on the GPU, and the GPU I have is the RX560 4GB. I am wondering whether will I get a better performance by going for the Ryzen 7 1700 instead of the Ryzen 5 1600.

Getting a more powerful GPU is out of my budget. I have a B350 motherboard coming in the mail, I just need to know what CPU I should get.

Comment: What do you intend to use Davinci Resolve for specifically?

Comment: I will be editing RAW 4K video (flat file) shot on the iPhone 6s, so will be dealing with color correction, effects etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either CPU will be fine but for heavy editing or rendering workloads you'd be better served getting a Ryzen 7 1700. The extra process threads will shorten your production downtime.

This will really end up being a budget-driven decision for you. If this machine is to fuel a hobby and your budget is on the tight side, get the Ryzen 5. If you're building this for professional production and intend to use it to earn income, then absolutely get the Ryzen 7 over the Ryzen 5 if your budget allows.

You could also wait a few months, as AMD is rumored to have a new professional-grade lineup of processors using the Zen architecture between Q3 and Q4, but that depends on your timeline.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just wondering that if the GPU the bottleneck anyway no matter if I go for the Ryzen 5 or 7